# error while setting cookies in php

Tags: php, cookies

This is my directory structure

```
main folder (public_html)
index.php

sub-folder1
   subindex1.php
   subfirst1.php

sub-folder2
   subindex2.php
   subfirst2.php
```

This is my directory structure.
Main folder is public_html. I have two sub-folders- sub folder 1 and sub folder 2.

I am running a script in subfolder1's subindex1.php to set a cookie in subfolder2 so that it can be accessed by subindex2.php

This is what I am doing now.

After doing some backend calculations, I'm setting cookies like this from `subindex1.php` and then does a redirect to `subindex2.php`

```
setcookie('id', "", time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 30, '/../sub-folder2/');
setcookie('token', "", time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 30, '/../sub-folder2/');             
header("Location: ../sub-folder2/subindex2.php");
```

Page redirects but cookies are not being set.

Is this the way to define the cookie path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your path is incorrect. By starting with `/`, you are starting from your root directory. Use the following:

```
setcookie('id', "", time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 30, '/sub-folder2/'); // ../sub-folder2/
setcookie('token', "", time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 30, '/sub-folder2/');  // ../sub-folder2/           
header("Location: ../sub-folder2/subindex2.php");
```

Check the manual [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) for any doubts.

Answer (score 1):

from php manual

> The path on the server in which the cookie will be available on. If
>   set to '/', the cookie will be available within the entire domain . If
>   set to '/foo/', the cookie will only be available within the /foo/
>   directory and all sub-directories such as /foo/bar/ of domain . The
>   default value is the current directory that the cookie is being set
>   in.

```
setcookie('id', "", time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 30, '/../sub-folder2/');
setcookie('token', "", time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 30, '/../sub-folder2/');
```

change to

```
setcookie('id', "", time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 30, '/');
setcookie('token', "", time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 30, '/');
```

or you want to this only to work for sub-folder2 only then  :

```
setcookie('id', "", time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 30, '../sub-folder2/');
setcookie('token', "", time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 30, '../sub-folder2/');
```